# How FirebaseMessagingService start after login activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible launch `FirebaseMessagingService` after some activity? Because when my app launch, `FirebaseMessagingService` call `onNewToken(String token) -> sendRegistrationToServer(token)`, but I need to send a token only when the user has logged in, so that I can map the user and the token. The best option would be if the `FirebaseMessagingService` skipped login and registration activities and then started. But I'm not sure if this can be done or not? And How?

Answer (score 1):

Let the **FirebaseMessagingService** run on the app launch as it is intended. When **onNewToken** is called **save the token to preferences**.

After the login, fetch the local token from preferences and send to your server.

Comment: I thought about it, but what happens when the token expired or user clear data

Comment: When token expires onNewToken will update the token on preferences.If you have a an "autologin" or "check-in" request when the app opens you can use it to send the latest token. Easiest way is to send FCM_TOKEN as a header in your requests. This way it always keeps updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another activity, just move the `sendRegistrationToServer(token)` to the next activity. Pass the value through the `Intent` then send it.

EDIT: Here is a sample code to generate token by demand (KOTLIN).

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            Log.e(this::class.java.simpleName, "FirebaseToken failed", task.exception)
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }
        firebaseToken = task.result!!.token
        println("FirebaseToken: $firebaseToken")
        SharedPrefUtil.instance.setPref(
            applicationContext,
            Constants.KEY_FIREBASE_TOKEN,
            firebaseToken
        )
    }
```

You can just ignore `sendRegistrationToServer`. I don't use it. As you can see, I save the token in SharedPreferences. After a successful login, retrieve it (can be on the next Activity) then send it to your server.

Relevant Link for you to read: [FirebaseInstanceId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId)

Comment: this is not possible because the FirebaseMessagingService calls these methods independently when the application starts, or I don’t understand something

Comment: I thought about SharedPreferences, but what happens when the token expired or user clear data

Comment: You don't have any control when the user clear's the app data. If that happens, the user probably will have to relogin again, then generate the instanceId again by demand, send it again to the server so it can get updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle using flag like **isLogin** and check in your onNewToken(). Even you are uploading to server you need user id in that user you are going to add token.. but while you are not logged in you don't have user id so in that case you can also check for user id is not null or not blank. While you get user id then you can add token to server using below method of kotlin.

```
fun getFirebaseDeviceToken(context: Context?) {
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId
                    .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener { task ->
                        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                            return@OnCompleteListener
                        }
                        if (task.result != null) {
                            val token = task.result!!.token
                            if (context != null) {
                                uploadUserDeviceInfo(context, token)
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }
```

Comment: FirebaseMessagingService triggered once after launch app after login method onNewToken() don't called

Comment: Yes. You can get token at any time by using mentioned method in answer